# Can we connect to secondary read access geo replicated blob storage account using 2.3 azure sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Can we connect to secondary read access geo replicated blob storage for accessing the blob contents, using 2.3 azure sdk?

I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like BlobClient.LocationMode is obselete now...

Comment: You're correct. BlobClient.LocationMode is obsolete. Use LocationMode in RequestOptions.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav for confirmation. Yes I am using the same with the RetryOptions LocationMode value as SecondaryOverPrimary. But bit confused, whether is it right approach to use the retryoptions property?